# Convert featured images into "product images"

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, plugin-wp-e-commerce

I am developing a large ecommerce site using Wordpress and WP Ecommerce plugin. I recently overhauled the theme and framework. Where as before I was only required to set a featured image for a product, the new framework insists the image be "used as product image" or "inserted into post".

As there are 3000 or so images/products; I need a quick way to set the featured images as post/thumbnail images.

Is there a quick solution to this? My initial instinct suggests I can copy the featured image value in the mySQL database and insert it into the corresponding value for thumbnail/product image with an SQL statement. Am I wrong? If not, does anyone have any idea how this phrase will look?

Answer (score 1):

That sounds weird because post thumbnails were changed to Featured Images  with WP 3.0.

I guess you're talking about some custom field or metabox your framework adds on post edit. You could grab `_thumbnail_id` which is the key in the `wp_postmeta` table that stores what you're looking for.

But to me you'd better use`wp_get_attachment_img_src`:

```
if(has_post_thumbnail($post->ID))
{
   $img = wp_get_attachment_img_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'the_image_size');
   //  URL is the first data of the array
   echo $img[0];
}
```